# Show that $E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{ 1 \leq p<q \leq n}f(X_p,X_q)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

*Let $(X_k)_k$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables and $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $f(X_1,X_2) \in L^1$ and for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,f(x,y)=f(y,x).$ Let for $n \geq 2,Y_n=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{ 1 \leq p<q \leq n}f(X_p,X_q)$ and $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(Y_n,Y_{n+1},...)$.*

*Show that for $n \geq 2, Y_n=E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_n].$*

We have that

\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \leq p<q \leq n}f(X_p,X_q)&=E\left[\sum_{1 \leq p<q \leq n}f(X_p,X_q)\mid Y_n \right]
\\&=\sum_{1 \leq p <q \leq n}E [f(X_p,X_q)\mid Y_n ]
\\&=\sum_{1 \leq p<q \leq n}E [f(X_1,X_2)\mid Y_n ]
\\&=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}E [f(X_1,X_2)\mid Y_n ]
\end{align}

which is true since for $1 \leq p < q \leq n, P_{(X_p,X_q,U_n)}=P_{(X_1,X_2,U_n)}.$

How to verify that $Y_n=E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_n ]$ ?

Comment: I like this problem, +1 , was it in a particular book that you are reading?

Comment: Hi, it's an exercise on U-statistics and martingales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F_{n}^m$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variables $U_n,\dots,U_m$. Then $(\mathcal F_n^m)_{m\geqslant n}$ is a filtration. By the martingale convergence theorem, it suffices to show that for each fixed $m$,$\mathbb E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal F_n^m]=U_n$.

Let $\mathcal C$ be the collection of the sets of the form $\bigcap_{i=n}^m \{U_i\in B_i\}$, where $B_i$ is a Borel subset of the real line. Then $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-systm generating $\mathcal F_n^m$. Therefore, it suffices to prove that
$$\mathbb E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mathbb 1_{\bigcap_{i=n}^m \{U_i\in B_i\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[U_n\mathbb 1_{\bigcap_{i=n}^m \{U_i\in B_i\}}\right]
$$
for each Borel subsets $B_n,\dots,B_m$ of the real line. This comes from the fact that $U_n=\frac 1{C^2_n}f_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ with $f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac 1{\binom n2}\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}f(x_i,x_j)=\frac 1{2\binom n2}\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq j\leqslant n}f(x_i,x_j)$ by symmetry of $f$. As a consequence, $U_n=g_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $g_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac 1{2\binom n2}\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq j\leqslant n}f(x_i,x_j)$ and $g_n$ is symmetric in all its arguments. Consequently, $(X_1,X_2,U_n,\dots,U_m)$ has the same distribution as $(X_p,X_q,U_n,\dots,U_m)$ for $1\leqslant p<q\leqslant n$ and it follows that
$$\mathbb E\left[f(X_1,X_2)\mathbb 1_{\bigcap_{i=n}^m \{U_i\in B_i\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[f(X_p,X_q)\mathbb 1_{\bigcap_{i=n}^m \{U_i\in B_i\}}\right].$$

Comment: Nice! I think a $\pi$-system isn't necessary because $P_{(X_1,X_2,U_n...,U_m)}=P_{(X_p,X_q,U_n,...,U_m)}$ and it follows that $E[f(X_1,X_2)|\mathcal{F}_n^m]=U_n$ to conclude using the martingale convergence theorem as you did!

Comment: Another way that doesn't use the martingale convergence theorem is to use the following property (which David Pechersky used implicitly): If $Y$ is $\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I}\mathcal{G}_i)$-measurable then in order to prove that $E[X|\sigma(\bigcup_{i \in I}\mathcal{G}_i)]=Y$ it's sufficient to prove that for every finite $J \subset I,H_j \in \mathcal{G}_j,E[X1_{\bigcap_{i \in J}H_j}]=E[Y1_{\bigcap_{i \in J}H_j}].$

Answer (score 3):

Since the $\sigma$- algebra $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is generated by sets of the form $\{Y_{n}\in{A_{n}}, Y_{n+1}\in{A_{n+1}}, ..., Y_{n+k}\in{A_{n+k}}\}$ where $A_{n}, A_{n+1}, ..., A_{n+k}$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, to verify that $\mathbb{E}(f(X_{1},X_{2})|\mathcal{F}_{n})=Y_{n}$, it suffices to show that:

$$\int_{Y_{n}\in{A_{n}}, Y_{n+1}\in{A_{n+1}}, ..., Y_{n+k}\in{A_{n+k}}} f(X_{1},X_{2})d\mathbb{P}=\int_{Y_{n}\in{A_{n}}, Y_{n+1}\in{A_{n+1}}, ..., Y_{n+k}\in{A_{n+k}}} Y_{n}d\mathbb{P}$$

To this effect, notice that the values of $Y_{n}, Y_{n+1}, Y_{n+2}, ...$ are invariant under permutation of $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$. Thus:

$$ \int_{Y_{n}\in{A_{n}}, Y_{n+1}\in{A_{n+1}}, ..., Y_{n+k}\in{A_{n+k}}} f(X_{1},X_{2})d\mathbb{P}=\int_{Y_{n}\in{A_{n}}, Y_{n+1}\in{A_{n+1}}, ..., Y_{n+k}\in{A_{n+k}}} f(X_{i},X_{j})d\mathbb{P}$$

for any choice of $i,j$ such that $1\leq{i}<j\leq{n}$. Summing over all such $i$ and $j$ on both sides of the equation above and then dividing by $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ then gives us the desired result.

Comment: Did you use the following fact: if $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{G} \cup \sigma(X))$ then $E[X|\mathcal{G} \cup \mathcal{F}]=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ ?

Comment: No- where do you think I'm using this?

Comment: What I am trying to say is: the property mentioned in the above comment is useful to prove that $E[X_1|\sigma(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k,\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k....)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k},$ I was wondering if it could be used here

Comment: Oh I just saw our answer which is actually very similar to mine. I keep it as there are the ideas about the invariance under permutations of $X_1,...,X_n$.

Comment: So the result you've stated is true: if $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of $\sigma{(\mathcal{G}\cup\sigma{(X)})}$ then it is certainly the case that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}\cup{\mathcal{F}}]=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$. However I don't think you can apply this here because it would require that $Y_n$ is independent of $Y_{n+1}, Y_{n+2}, Y_{n+3}, ...$, which I don't think is true in general.