# $\lim_{n \to \infty}E[f(X_1,X_2)|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

The exercise is related to a question that was asked before: [Show that $E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{ 1 \leq p<q \leq n}f(X_p,X_q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255045/show-that-efx-1-x-2-mid-mathcalf-n-frac2nn-1-sum-1-leq-pq-le), where we proved that for every $n \geq 2, Y_n=E[f(X_1,X_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_n].$

From the martingale convergence theorem, we deduce that $Y_n$ converges a.s. and in $L^1$ to $Y_{\infty}=E[f(X_1,X_2)|\bigcap_{n}\mathcal{F}_n].$

How can we prove that $Y_{\infty}$ is a.s. equal to an $\bigcap_{n}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$-measurable random variable? And therefore to deduce from this that $Y_{\infty}=E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ a.s.

Attempt: tried to consider $\limsup_{n}Y_n$ but I do not know if this will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality $Y_{\infty}=E[f(X_1,X_2)]$ a.s. can be deduced from the following reasoning. First,
$$
\mathbb E\left\lvert Y_n-\frac1{\binom n2}\sum_{k_0\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}f(X_i,X_j)\right\rvert\leqslant \frac{k_0n}{\binom n2}\mathbb E\left[\left\lvert f(X_1,X_2)\right\rvert\right]
$$
hence for each $k_0$, $Y_\infty$ is in the limit in $L^1$ of the sequence $\left(\frac1{\binom n2}\sum_{k_0\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}f(X_i,X_j)\right)_{n \geqslant 1}$, which is $\sigma(X_j,j\geqslant k_0)$-measurable. As a consequence $Y_\infty$ should be almost surely equal to a $\bigcap_{k_0\geqslant 1}\sigma(X_j,j\geqslant k_0)$-measurable random variable hence constant.

Comment: I initially believed that $\mathcal F_n$ was generated by $X_i, i\geqslant n$. Now I edited accordingly.

Comment: Why wouldn't the convergence in $L^1$ not be enough? We have that $\mathbb E[Y_\infty\mid \sigma(X_j,j\geqslant k_0)]$ is also the limit of $\left(\frac1{\binom n2}\sum_{k_0\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}f(X_i,X_j)\right)_{n \geqslant 1}$, because conditional expectation is a contraction. Therefore, $Y_\infty=$\mathbb E[Y_\infty\mid \sigma(X_j,j\geqslant k_0)]$

Comment: Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

You already know that $Y_n$ converges almost surely, so you already know that $Y_{\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n$, therefore no need to consider the limes superior. It is clear that $Y_n$ is $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$-measurable by definition. A priori, $Y_{\infty}$ is therefore almost surely equal to a $\sigma(X_1,X_2,\dots)$-measurable random variable (I'll drop the disclaimer about almost surely equal sometimes in the following for the sake of brevity). However, if we leave away all the terms involving $X_1$ in the definition of $Y_n$, the limit is unchanged (I'd advise to make sure you understand that and check it), so $Y_{\infty}$ is even $ \sigma(X_2,X_3,\dots)$-measurable. Proceeding inductively, we see that $Y_{\infty}$ is actually $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$-measurable for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., $Y_{\infty}$ is $\cap_{n} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$-measurable. By Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, this implies that $Y_{\infty}$ is almost surely equal to a constant. Since $Y_{n}$ converges in $L^1$, we have
$$ |\mathbb{E}[Y_n] - \mathbb{E}[Y_{\infty}]| \leq \mathbb{E}[|Y_n - Y_{\infty}|] \to 0 $$
Since $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[f(X_1,X_2)]$ and $Y_{\infty}$ is almost surely constant, it follows that $Y_{\infty} = \mathbb{E}[f(X_1,X_2)]$ almost surely.

Comment: In order to remove the terms with $X_1,$ can we prove that $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{p=2}^{n}f(X_1,X_k)$ converges a.s. to $0$ ? (we have convergence in $L^1$)

Comment: actually I don't see how to prove that it converges almost surely. But if we have convergence in $L^1$, then there is a subsequence which converges almost surely, which is enough to deduce the measurability statement.

Comment: I think to obtain the measurability of $Y_{\infty},$ we need convergence point by point, not a.s. convergence unless the probability space is complete or by considering $\limsup$